# login devise teacher model using TeacherID while student model using email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, rails-models

Is it possible to allow one devise model login on basis of the username or some other unique id while other one using default devise email authentication process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [multiple Devise User models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models) for each role and use [custom authentication methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address). There is even a gem for creating custom Devise authentication strategies - [DeviseCustomAuthenticatable](https://github.com/AMekss/devise_custom_authenticatable).

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I want to user the TeacherID both as username and password, how would I achieve this? while other model uses email and password mechanism for login process

Comment: It is described in the second link, but this page may be also helpful: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address